# Web service headers

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to make a web service call and include and authorization cookie in the header.

I see another site do this, using fiddler and the call looks like -

```
GET url/services/events HTTP/1.1
Host: url
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
X-Auth-Token: 33d131bb-37b4-4d87-b646-6edccab4f294
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: url/api-docs/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: knownUser=true
```

How do I code in "X-Auth-Token: 33d131bb-37b4-4d87-b646-6edccab4f294".

Here is my C# code.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", "33d131bb-37b4-4d87-b646-6edccab4f294");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("url?keywords=Taylor%20Swift&eventType=CONCERT&city=Mexico%20City"), new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sp), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

But I keep getting a 500 error. (StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error')

What is the ocrrect syntax to get that token passed intot he web service call?

Comment: The authentication token you scraped might well be limited to a certain point in time. Do you see the same authentication token if you look in fiddler now? The authentication token might also be linked to a specific requesting domain. If anyone could just grab the token from fiddler and use it, it would be pretty weak authentication.

Comment: Try to duplicate the entire call, perhaps the server is checking for knownUser=true, or even User-Agent